# java to mysql. I need convert from string parametre to timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing, unparseable

I'm trying to parser String to Timestamp because I need to save this data on bbdd mysql.

```
String dateString: "2018-10-17T22:37:10.000+0000";
java.sql.Timestamp timeStampDate = null;
try {
        DateFormat formatter;
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(dateString);
        timeStampDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        log.debug("ERROR parser String to Timestamp to save bbdd. ", e.getMessage());
    }
```

When I run my app I get this catch message:

> ERROR parser String to Timestamp to save bbdd. Unparseable date: "2018-10-17T22:37:10.000+0000"

Can anybody help me?

Comment: First, I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Second, for saving into MySQL it’s probably better to save an `Instant`, an `OffsetDateTime` or a `LocalDateTime`than a `Timestamp` (another poorly designed and outdated class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your mask to

`DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS");`

so you have

```
java.sql.Timestamp timeStampDate = null;
String dateString = "2018-10-17T22:37:10.000+0000";

try {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    Date date = formatter.parse(dateString);
    timeStampDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**By the way** you should not need to `cast` the `Date`

**Apologies** for my slackness, in my haste I did not test the output and as per @andreas comment, the correct mask is actually `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: thanks @Scary. Now it is working. and yes, I dont need to cast the Date.

Comment: Sorry, that is wrong. First, it's `HH`, not `hh`. Second, ignoring the +0 time zone offset means you get the wrong time, e.g. I'm on US east coast, so running that code would get me time `2018-10-17 22:37:10.000 EDT`, which is not the same as time `2018-10-17T22:37:10.000+0000`, because that would be `2018-10-17 18:37:10.000 EDT`. Correct format string is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX");
    String dateString = "2018-10-17T22:37:10.000+0000";
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);

    System.out.println("Parsed datetime: " + odt);
```

Output from this code is:

> Parsed datetime: 2018-10-17T22:37:10Z

For saving into MySQL it’s good to use a datetime object, but the `Timestamp` class has design problems and is now long outdated. I am sorry that I don’t have the experience with MySQL, but I think the following should work:

```
    PreparedStatement ps = myDatabaseConnection.prepareStatement(
            "insert into my_table (my_timestamp) values (?)");
    ps.setObject(1, odt);
```

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.