# Parsing of ISO 8601 Date String in Java

Tags: java, datetime, iso8601

Is `2021-07-27T09:58:51.000+0000` a right ISO 8601 format? Could not locate an online validator which claims to say if this is compliant or not.

Had issues while parsing this date below are the ways tried and the result is below:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.DateTimeException;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "2021-07-27T09:58:51.000+0000";
        try {
            System.out.println("Success 001: " + OffsetDateTime.parse(s));
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            System.err.println("Fail: OffsetDateTime.parse: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
            System.out.println("Success 002: " + df1.parse(s));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.err.println("Fail: SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
            System.out.println("Success 003: " + df1.parse(s));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.err.println("Fail: SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX\"): " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            TemporalAccessor ta = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.parse(s);
            Instant i = Instant.from(ta);
            System.out.println("Success 004: " + Date.from(i));
        } catch (DateTimeException e) {
            System.err.println("Fail: TemporalAccessor: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Success 005: " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(s));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.err.println("Fail: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Success 006: " + org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.parseDate(s,
                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.err.println("Fail: org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Success 007: " + new org.joda.time.DateTime(s).toDate());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.err.println("Fail: org.joda.time.DateTime: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Result

```
Fail: OffsetDateTime.parse: Text '2021-07-27T09:58:51.000+0000' could not be parsed at index 23
Success 002: Tue Jul 27 15:28:51 IST 2021
Fail: SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"): Unparseable date: "2021-07-27T09:58:51.000+0000"
Fail: TemporalAccessor: Text '2021-07-27T09:58:51.000+0000' could not be parsed at index 23
Fail: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter: 2021-07-27T09:58:51.000+0000
Success 006: Tue Jul 27 15:28:51 IST 2021
Success 007: Tue Jul 27 15:28:51 IST 2021
```

From the above result, could you suggest a recommended way of parsing the above kind of date and any other ISO date string?

Comment: Try `2021-07-27T09:58:51.000+00:00`, which I think is the valid ISO format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't OffsetDateTime parse '2016-08-24T18:38:05.507+0000' in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133828/why-cant-offsetdatetime-parse-2016-08-24t183805-5070000-in-java-8). Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823627/java-string-to-datetime), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43360852/cannot-parse-string-in-iso-8601-format-lacking-colon-in-offset-to-java-8-date), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230408/parse-and-retrieve-timezone-offset-from-date-time)?

Comment: I’m unsure which original you find best. There’s also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48412345/convert-date-into-aest-using-java), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666263/java-date-parsing-why-do-i-get-an-error), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53291240/java-to-mysql-i-need-convert-from-string-parametre-to-timestamp), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61269697/convert-a-string-to-zoneddatetime), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65844748/how-to-parse-zoneddatetime-with-milliseconds) and more.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The string in the question is valid according to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) too. The colon in the offset is optional.

Comment: I unconditionally recommend parsing into an`OffsetDateTime` using the two-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse(CharSequence, DateTimeFormatter)` and a custom formatter like `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).appendOffset("+HHmmss", "+0000").toFormatter(Locale.ROOT)`.

Comment: [See the recommended way run live on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/KXbFCx).

Comment: @BobKuhar, very much the same problem what I am trying to solve